# using find or other command to restrict the search of a file name extension within the same directory

Tags: shell, find

I have a directory which has multiple subdirectories in it. I am looping through the subdirectories one by one. Then I change the directory using cd. If in that sub directory, I have a file having an extension .partial, save the file name. Then I nee to print the sub directory name and partial file name. I have written something like this

```
for f in *
do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        cd "$f"
        a=$(find ./ -name "*.partial")
        if [ -e "$a" ];then
            echo -e "$f" "\t" "$a"
        fi
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

The problem with `find` is that it recursively looks for `.partial` file extensions in further sub directories, which I don't want. How can I restrict it to only current directory?

Comment: Stepping backwards from your process description a moment, what is it you're actually trying to achieve? Is it to list all the `.partial` files in each subdirectory?

Comment: find out files which are downloaded partially and failed so that I can resume their downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` utility supports the option `-maxdepth`

> -maxdepth levels
>   Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of
>   directories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0 means only
>   apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.

To restrict `find` to the specified directory, you can add the option `-maxdepth 1`.

---

If you're trying to list all regular files `*.partial` at depth 2 with an output similar to that in your question, you could try a command such as

```
 find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.partial' -printf '%h\t./%f\n'
```

which could give an output similar to

```
./b    ./file2.partial
./b    ./file3.partial
./a    ./file1.partial
```

Answer (score 3):

To just output the full pathname for each `.partial` file relative to the current directory:

```
printf '%s\n' ./*/*.partial
```

Setting the `nullglob` shell option in `bash` would make this not output the pattern itself if there is no match (there would still be an empty line outputted), and setting `dotglob` would additionally match hidden names.

---

The following splits these pathnames up in a directory path and a filename part:

```sh
for name in ./*/*.partial; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "${name%/*}" "${name##*/}"
done
```

This would print the subdirectory name and the `.partial` filename for each `.partial` name found in any subdirectory of the current directory.

In `bash`, you may additionally want to set the shell option `dotglob` if you need to be able to match hidden names as well.

The two parameter substitutions could be replaced by calls to `dirname` and `basename`:

```sh
for name in ./*/*.partial; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(dirname "$name")" "$(basename "$name")"
done
```

---

A variation of the above for printing the subdirectory name only once (this requires a `bash`-like shell for the `${*%%*/}` parameter expansion which removes the directory paths and leaves the filenames, for each positional parameter):

```sh
IFS=$'\t'
for dirname in ./*/; do
    set -- "$dirname"/*.partial;
    [ -f "$1" ] && printf '%s\t%s\n' "$dirname" "${*##*/}"
done
```

This loops over each subdirectory and expands the `*.partial` globbing pattern in each.  If the first match is a regular file (or a link to one), the subdirectory name is printed followed by the names that matched the pattern, with the directory path removed.

Comment: Doesn't that print the directory name for each file? My understanding is that output should be `directory1 file1 file2 ... fileN`, one line per directory

Comment: @roaima This is how I interpreted "Then I nee to print the sub directory name and partial file name."

Comment: @roaima I added a bit of code for your interpretation of the question as well.

Comment: Actually with or without `-a`, that won't work properly to have two columns with dir and file as `zsh` sorts the list. Adding `oN` to disable sorting would help, but the list wouldn't be sorted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've deleted that bit for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `find` you can do something like this

```
for dir in *
do
    files=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.partial' -printf "%f\n" | xargs)
    [[ -n "$files" ]] && printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir" "$files"
done
```

If you don't have GNU `find` you can emulate the `-printf '%f\n'` at the expense of some efficiency, like this

```
for dir in *
do
    files=$(cd "$dir" && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.partial' -print | sed 's!^./!!' | xargs)
    [[ -n "$files" ]] && printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir" "$files"
done
```

Neither solution handles files with newlines or strange-printing characters, but if you are listing files in a directory on a single line I would expect you not to have weird filenames. If you have a shell that doesn't understand `[[ ... ]]` just replace the double brackets with single brackets, `[ ... ]`.